# Spring boot couldn't map the my html files

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

So basically i got this controller :

```
package com.example.controllor;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Controllors {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String index(){
    return "index";
  }
  @RequestMapping("/login")
  public String login(){
    return "login";
  }
  @RequestMapping("/register")
  public String register(){
    return "register";
  }
}
```

and i got those html pages  :
[these 3 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6sbG.png)

the index html works fine but login.html and register.html don't work. (it says Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jun 12 02:37:23 CEST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). )

any help ? i'm lost

My Thymeleaf declaration

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you added Thymeleaf dependency?

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao check my post i have updated it; and yes i did

Comment: What is the url you try to reach?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your package structure.
As your main class is in `com.example.demo` package, Spring will consider it as base package and scan all subpackages under it for beans. 
 So, you have two options

1. Move your controller classes to `com.example.demo.controller` package.
2. In `@SpringApplication` annotation, add `scanBasePackages` like `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example")`